# How to fill grid dynamically MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, grid

I have a grid at My View:

```
<div id="grid">
    @grid.GetHtml(
        mode: WebGridPagerModes.FirstLast | WebGridPagerModes.NextPrevious,
        firstText: "<<",
        previousText: "<",
        nextText: ">",
        lastText: ">>",
        columns: grid.Columns(
           grid.Column("Column1", header: "Column1", format: @<text>@item.Test1</text>),
           grid.Column("Column2", header: "Column2", format: @<text>@item.Test2</text>)
        )
     )
</div>
```

I can execute a query when I enter  my window.
But, how can I fill this column with rows from a database when I press a button? My grid is very simple, and I can't find any example with simple grids.

Comment: Have you tried setting the grid in a partial view? Have the button send a command back to the controller and return an object used to fill the grid.

Comment: Are you trying to fill the table or just a specific column with specific data?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.elylucas.net/post/Using-a-grid-that-can-sort-page-and-filter-in-AspNet-MVC3e28093Part-1e28093Using-the-WebGrid-WebHelper.aspx

Check this tutorial out. It is the same principal except you won't be searching you will just need to hit a button and the view re-render itself.